# Switch with a big antenna

Tags: wireless-networking, antenna, signal-strength

Not a code problem but an architecture/infrastructure one.

I have a single board computer device (SBC) with an IP setup that currently chats to a laptop via a switch. All on a private network that can easily have more of these SBC added to enlarge the network. Ip addressing is not dynamic, each SBC has a fixed one.

That's the background, now I want to remove the switch (maybe), but mostly remove all the physical connections and have it wireless with a pretty broad range (like not meters but 100s of meters).

I don't want to offer up too many suggestions right away, I'd rather hear your ideas/product suggestions. Keep in mind that the SBC has minimal hardware connections so anything I could put on the end of an RJ35 would be ideal!

Comment: Dont sign off with "GO!", it gives the impression that you think we *owe* you an answer

Comment: My apologise... People have been using this sign off around me a lot in the last few weeks and it's horribly catching, duly edited.

Comment: What are your requirements regarding data throughput? WLAN might be difficult in 100s of meters range. Others may have significantly lower throughput rates..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, depending on the details of your data transfer, speed, and reliability requirements, you might be able to get an 802.11 network of some flavor set up.  USB attached wireless adapters for the SBC's.

Comment: Unfortunately I have very limited connectivity on these SBC's... They're already housed in pretty sturdy boxes and there is no USB.  To explain a little further... They happen to be running a very stripped down vanilla Linux distro and I am currently using socket based communication for the chatting between the SBC and the 'mother' processes. The data transfer is pretty minimal, but reliability is important.

Comment: Bit of a mouthful I know...

Comment: SBC make/model? I/O options? Obviously there's a LAN port - what else?

Comment: Unfortunately a hardware change is not possible in the time frame. I think, I'm going to go with a wireless bridge and boosters and/or a second machine that can pick up the original network to act as a bridge to the SBC. I had a read of the similar questions on SU and I think I have a better handle on a solution. I guess I should read more!